# DAC Field not persisting when saving a record

Tags: acumatica, dac

I have a graph called InvoiceEntry (AP301000). This graph contains a DAC called APInvoice/APRegister.

When I save the APInvoice record, the OrigDocAmt field clears whatever value was in there, and sets it to null in the DB. I have no idea why....

Answer (score 0):

Use menu item `CUSTOMIZATION->Inspect Element` then click on one of the form header fields to lookup the exact DAC and Graph names which are `APInvoice` and `APInvoiceEntry`:

[image]

Open `Source Code` page (SM204570) and search for the `class APInvoiceEntry`. Once you have located the file, expand the regions and search for assignation to the target field `APInvoice.OrigDocAmt`:

[image]

There are multiple reasons why this field value will be set to 0 by this page, some pasted below.
Introducing different behaviors for it could lead to unexpected issues because it is heavily managed by the system already.

```
sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<APInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt>(doc, null, null);
sender.SetValueExt<APInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt>(doc, 0m);
Document.Cache.RaiseFieldUpdated<APInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt>(doc, 0m);
```